# Create table with copying columnname,type and then insert records

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Database :: .db (SQLite) ; code language :: C#

I want to create one temp table and then insert values into it into

currently I am inserting records like below

`create table temp1 AS Select A1, A2 from TableA`

**Current Problem ::**

There are **more then 1 billion records** (or can be more ) in TableA 
so because of that code is getting system outofMemoryExeception.

**What I think**

1. Create Table
2. Insert records (everytime 5000 - upto finish)

For same I think,

1. Create table only with columnname(A1) and it's datatype(Integer), columnname(A2) and it's datatype(CHAR(3)) (I only passing `SELECT A1, A2 from TABLEA`)
2. INSERT records :: 5000 in one loop. (I don't know how can i limit this ?)

I mean 
SELECT first 5000 records then
SELECT 5001 to 10000 records then
SELECT 10001 to 15000 records
...
...

I know...

`SELECT A1, A2 from TABLEA limit 5000`  (This will get first 5000 records but how after this ?)

Is there any other logic which can satisfy my requirement ?

SELECT INTO not support by SQLite

Comment: Are you using `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE TEMP TABLE`? Are you using an in-memory database?

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to believe SQLite designers wrote their app on the basis that they had enough memory for any operation all the time. That would seem a foolish assumption...

Comment: @CL. I am using CREATE TABLE only.... I am not storing it in-memory database but creating it because i need to update each record with some external values and then run my actual query

Comment: @TonyHopkinson .. As said that code is getting system OutofMemoryExeception

Comment: SQLite itself cannot throw an `OutOfMemoryExeception`, and does not need memory for all copied rows. Show the exact code that you're using to execute that SQL statement.

Comment: Barely used SQLlite myself, but I've run into a few OOM situations and in general the bit of code where the exception was raised usually has nothing to do with the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
SELECT A1, A2 from TABLEA limit 0,5000 //for first 5000 rows
SELECT A1, A2 from TABLEA limit 5000,10000 //for Next 5000 rows
```

Comment: First one would be the Create Table Command. Subsequent ones would be insert into presumably?

Comment: This is extremely inefficient for large offsets.